# How to make a "StringWriterMarkupBuilder"

Tags: groovy

How can I make a type which is a `MarkupBuilder` but has default constructor which is initialized with a `StringWriter` and overrides `toString()` to call the `toString()` on the `StringWriter`?

The idea is like the following, but of course initializing instance variables before super constructor calls is not allowed:

```
class StringWriterMarkupBuilder extends MarkupBuilder {
    final def sw = new StringWriter()
    StringWriterMarkupBuilder() {
        super(sw)
    }

    @Override String toString() {
        sw.toString()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do this with the `metaClass` like so:

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

MarkupBuilder createSWMB() {
  new StringWriter().with { sw ->
    new MarkupBuilder( sw ).with { mb ->
      mb.metaClass.toString = { -> sw.toString() }
      mb
    } 
  }
}

MarkupBuilder mb = createSWMB()
mb.root {
  names {
    name( first:'tim', second:'yates' )
  }
}
println mb.toString()
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I finally figured out a solution by digging into the Groovy source code for MarkupBuilder!:

```
class StringWriterMarkupBuilder extends MarkupBuilder {
    StringWriterMarkupBuilder() {
        //MarkupBuilder.this(new IndentPrinter(new PrintWriter(writer)))
        super(new StringWriter()) 
    }

    @Override String toString() {
        //IndentPrinter.PrintWriter.StringWriter
        return super.getPrinter().out.out.toString()
    }
}
```